# Xamarin - iOS - Storyboard/Button - Background images disappears on build/run

Tags: ios, xamarin

**When building the app on a physical device, background images don't show up.**

I am working in the Storyboad editor in Visual Studio.

I wanted to put a image background on a button to try out working with a nice UI. 
With this I am experiencing weird behavior and issues:

The images are in a subfolder to Resources called "Images", and they are set to "BundleResource". The name of the specific image is "start.png". 
On the background option on the button I can choose "Images/start.png" and on the storyboard the button looks correct.

If I then build the app and try and run it on a physical device attached to the build host, the background is not shown on the device. At the same time the graphics on the button in the storyboard disappears. 
If I select the button the background field is now empty.

Comment: We really don't care about your background... Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get the most benefit out of your questions.

Comment: Apparently it is a big issue how you write your question. So now I edited it from the suggestions. Personally I do not mind knowing if the person asking the question has experience with the area the question concerns, but ok it has been changed.

Comment: I'm very sorry for my rudeness. Great work on editing the question. What I meant was it's annoying to read 3 paragraphs before I get to what the problem is, which is why your questions should be formulated like: "I can't do this, this is how I tried and it's not working.".

Comment: Well ok, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

for the image which you set using Images/start.png set from visual studio is because windows understands the path with "\" and MAC understands "/".

So if you've set the path using "\" from Visual Studio will provide auto intellisense with image name and path but if set using "/" from Visual Studio, it won't provide intellisense and clears the property once you run in simulator or on device.